# How do I put text file into a hash table in Java?

Tags: java, hash, hashtable, bufferedreader

I have a text file, I want to read it and place it into my hash table. 
Then print it.

I have written a block of code, what am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        Hashtable< Integer, String > hash = new Hashtable< Integer, String >();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader( new FileReader ("students.txt"));
        String line = "";

        int i = 0;
        while (line != null){
            line = rd.readLine();
            hash.put(i, line);
            i++;
        }
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < hash.size() ; j++){
            System.out.println(hash.get(j));
        }


    }
```

Comment: From a first glance this looks good; so some example output/error message is required. Besides: why are you using a Hashtable when you use it with an numeric index - why not using an ArrayList<String> instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code looks good . Correcting one bug below

```
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("students.txt"));
         while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(thisLine);
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using your code and I have corrected some bugs...

I think, this code is not right but he works :)

```
try{
    Hashtable< Integer, String > hash = new Hashtable< Integer, String >();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader( new FileReader ("students.txt"));
    String line;

    int i = 0;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
        hash.put(i, line);
        i++;
    }
    for ( int j = 0 ; j < hash.size() ; j++){
        System.out.println(hash.get(j));
    }
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){}catch (IOException e) {}
```